# WordPress Duplicating Post as a Custom Admin Menu

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a separate menu item for my Orders that works exactly like Posts and Pages. I was hoping there was a simple way of doing this. I had the idea of a menu item showing only Posts in a specific category but I would like the ability to create new posts only in the orders category and hide the orders in the post admin dashboard. Any ideas of how to do this?